# How to compare two date and to find out whether the date difference is within 3 months in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know how to compare two date and to find out whether the date difference is within 3 months in SQL Server?

Example if I have 2 dates:

```
Start_Date = '2013-02-01'
End_Date = '2013-04-10'
```

How can I compare two date and to find out whether the date difference is within 3 months in SQL Server?

Comment: `where Datediff (M, start_date, end_date) <= 3`

Comment: What does "within three months" mean (exactly)? For example, are Feb 28 and May 31 (92 days apart, non-leap year) "within three months"? How about Feb 1 and May 31 (109 days apart, non-leap year)? Does the definition of "within three months" change in a leap year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, start_date, end_date) <= 3
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbaa9/1)

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer using the two dates you provided in your question.  I gave it to you two ways.  The first column is the comparison of whether it is within 3 months.  The second column is simply the result of the SQL Server system function `DATEDIFF`.

```
DECLARE @Start_Date DATE = '2013-02-01',
        @End_Date   DATE = '2013-04-10'

SELECT CASE
           WHEN datediff(MONTH, @Start_Date, @End_Date) <= 3 THEN
               'True'
           ELSE
               'False'
       END AS [WithinThreeMonths]
     , datediff(MONTH, @Start_Date, @End_Date) [Months]
```